# Swift -Delete Custom Folder From Documents Directory

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

When recording videos I create a custom folder using `"/MyFolder"` like this:

```
guard let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first else { return }
let dirPath = "\(documentsPath)/MyFolder/Videos_\(UUID().uuidString).mp4"

let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)
// ...
```

Now I have a function to delete just custom folders:

```
func deleteCustom(folder: String) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    guard let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
    let customFolder = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folder)
    guard let filePaths = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: customFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: []) else { return }
    for filePath in filePaths {
        try? fileManager.removeItem(at: filePath)
    }
}
```

In the function parameter should I pass in `"MyFolder"` or `"/MyFolder"`?

Comment: "MyFolder", because `appendingPathComponent` adds `/` automatically.

Comment: @Asperi thanks! Post it as answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @LanceSamaria There is no need to enumerate all your files and remove them one by one. You can simply delete the whole customFolder `fileManager.removeItem(at: customFolder)`. If you want to keep an empty folder just create it again after deleting it. Btw don't ignore your errors. You should always catch them.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the advice, that makes a lot of sense and is easier. Quick question, how long does it take to delete the files when iterating vs deleting it at once like you suggested?

Comment: @LanceSamaria it will depend on the number of items inside your directory

Comment: @LeoDabus makes sense, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the function parameter should I pass in "MyFolder" or "/MyFolder"?

"MyFolder", because appendingPathComponent adds / automatically.